# PL/SQL getting average value in case statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, sum, case, average

THE TABLE:

```
+-----+----+----------+
| QTR | MO | PCT_PERF |
+-----+----+----------+
|   1 | 1  |       89 | 
|   1 | 2  |       73 |
|   1 | 3  |       95 |
+-----+----+----------+
```

### What is the proper syntax for this?

```
CASE WHEN QTR=1 THEN ROUND(SUM(PCT_PERF WHERE MO IN (1,2,3))/3,2)
 WHEN QTR=2 THEN ROUND(SUM(PCT_PERF WHERE MO IN (4,5,6))/3,2) 
 WHEN QTR=3 THEN ROUND(SUM(PCT_PERF WHERE MO IN (7,8,9))/3,2)
 ELSE ROUND(SUM(PCT_PERF WHERE MO IN (10,11,12))/3,2) END QTR_PCT
```

So that WHEN QTR is 1, QTR_PCT should be 86.
*(89+73+95)/3 = 85.67*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Oracle's `AVG` ("average") function should solve your problem. I don't have an Oracle database handy to confirm this:

```
SELECT QTR, ROUND(AVG(PCT_PERF), 2) AS QTR_PCT FROM ... GROUP BY QTR
```